# Getting the Type of a ContextBoundObject when intercepting a method call

Tags: c#, .net

I'm intercepting method calls into a ContextBoundObject. Is there a way to get hold of the Type of the object I'm calling when in the message sink?

Say I've got a class

```
 [Intercept]
 [Synchronization]
 public class Test : ContextBoundObject
 {
    [Timeout(10010)]
    public void Method()
    {
        // Do something
    }
 }
```

In the message sink before the call is put through to `Method` is there someway to get hold of the `Test` type so I can query the custom attribute `Timeout`? eg

```
public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
{
      Type type = GetType(); // << Need to get hold of Test type here
      object[] custom = type.GetMethod("Method").GetCustomAttributes(false);;
      TimeoutAttribute ta = custom[0] as TimeoutAttribute;
      int time = ta.Ticks;

      IMessage returnedMessage = _nextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
      return returnedMessage;
}
```

ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little messing I found it.

The type name is passed into SyncProcessMessage in the Properties dictionary in IMessage.

So the code above becomes

```
public IMessage SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
{
      Type type = Type.GetType(msg.Properties["__TypeName"].ToString());

      object[] custom = type.GetMethod("Method").GetCustomAttributes(false);
      TimeoutAttribute ta = custom[0] as TimeoutAttribute;
      int time = ta.Ticks;

      IMessage returnedMessage = _nextSink.SyncProcessMessage(msg);
      return returnedMessage;
}
```